# Excel VBA - Look down column A for specific value and hide all rows below activecell row?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following vba script to hide all rows with the matching cell value in column A of the Active Cell row:

```
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing And ActiveCell.Value = "-" Then

 BeginRow = 1
    EndRow = 50000
    ChkCol = 1

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -8) Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt

End If
```

So for instance if i have 5 rows all with the number 35 in column A like so:

```
A            I
35           Click to hide   <----- First Row
35           
35           
35           
35
```

Then all these rows will be hidden. However, i don't want the row of the first instance to be hidden.

Comment: Change BeginRow to 2? Whoever wrote this code for you made it pretty clear...

Comment: @vacip changing the beginRow would mean changing the look up range. i don't want to change the lookup range of my rows. I just want the first instance of the row with cell value 35 to not be hidden

Comment: Ah, that is different. Why don't you add an If to check if RowCnt>1?

Answer (score 0):

Add two variables (a variant to hold the value to be compared and a boolean to validate the first value found)

```
Dim vCllValue As Variant
Dim bl1stVal As Boolean
```

This is the revised code:

```
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing And ActiveCell.Value = "-" Then
    BeginRow = 1
    EndRow = 50000
    ChkCol = 1

    bl1stVal = False
    vCllValue = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -8).Value
    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = vCllValue Then
            If Not (bl1stVal) Then
                bl1stVal = True
            Else
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If: End If: Next: End If
```

*Noticed that the code compares the value in the row below the `ActiveCell` I'm assuming that part is correct, otherwise let me know and will do the necessary adjustments.*